# Dynamically pivot distinct values into column headers (ie months)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2 and was hoping for some help to dynamically create a column for each distinct date (month) I have in my dataset, where I can SUM the quantity per month by user.  So for example my data looks like:

```
Emp     Month       QTY
-------------------------
John    3/1/2016    20
John    3/1/2016    30
John    4/1/2016    15
John    6/1/2016    40
Jim     2/1/2016    25
Jim     4/1/2016    28
Jim     5/1/2016    15
Jim     5/1/2016    15
Jim     6/1/2016    32
Alex    4/1/2016    20
Alex    4/1/2016    20
Alex    4/1/2016    20
Alex    5/1/2016    45
```

and I'd like to just get the totals per month by `Emp`, like this:

```
Employee    2/1/2016    3/1/2016    4/1/2016    5/1/2016    6/1/2016
--------------------------------------------------------------------
John        0           50          15          0           40
Jim         25          0           28          30          32
Alex        0           0           60          45          0
```

I've seen some `PIVOT` and `CROSS APPLY` functions where the columns (month in this case) are specified and hardcoded before hand. Is there an easy way to dynamically create those column names based on the values within `[Month]` ?

Either way, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query

Answer (score 0):

PIVOT is great, but I use a stored procedure for the bulk of my Dynamic Pivots.

The source can be a table,view,#temp, or even sql

Notice that you can define additional aggregates (ie. Total, Min, Max, Avg, STD...).  You can also define additional Group By's as well

```
Exec [prc-Pivot] '#Temp','Month','sum(Qty)[]','Emp','count(*)[Records],sum(Qty)[Total],min(Qty)[Min],max(Qty)[Max],Avg(Qty)[Avg]'
```

Returns
[image]

And, just for fun...

```
Exec [prc-Pivot] 'Select *,Qtr=''Q''+concat(concat(DatePart(QQ,Month),''-''),Year(Month)) from #Temp','Emp','sum(Qty)[]','Qtr',null
```

[image]

The Stored Procedure

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[prc-Pivot] (
    @Source varchar(1000),          -- Any Table or Select Statement
    @PvotCol varchar(250),          -- Field name or expression ie. Month(Date)
    @Summaries varchar(250),        -- aggfunction(aggValue)[optionalTitle]
    @GroupBy varchar(250),          -- Optional additional Group By 
    @OtherCols varchar(500) )       -- Optional Group By or aggregates
AS

--Exec [prc-Pivot] 'Select Year=Year(TR_Date),* From [Chinrus-Series].[dbo].[DS_Treasury_Rates]','''Q''+DateName(QQ,TR_Date)','avg(TR_Y10)[-Avg]','Year','count(*)[Records],min(TR_Y10)[Min],max(TR_Y10)[Max],Avg(TR_Y10)[Avg]'


Set NoCount On
Set Ansi_Warnings Off

Declare @Vals varchar(max),@SQL varchar(max);
Set @Vals = ''
Set @OtherCols= IsNull(', ' + @OtherCols,'')
Set @Source = case when @Source Like 'Select%' then @Source else 'Select * From '+@Source end
Create Table #TempPvot  (Pvot varchar(100))
Insert Into #TempPvot
Exec ('Select Distinct Convert(varchar(100),' + @PvotCol + ') as Pvot FROM (' + @Source + ') A')
Select @Vals = @Vals + ', isnull(' + Replace(Replace(@Summaries,'(','(CASE WHEN ' + @PvotCol + '=''' + Pvot +  ''' THEN '),')[', ' END),0) As [' + Pvot ) From #TempPvot Order by Pvot
Drop Table #TempPvot
Set @SQL = Replace('Select ' + Isnull(@GroupBy,'') + @OtherCols + @Vals + ' From (' + @Source + ') PvtFinal ' + case when Isnull(@GroupBy,'')<>'' then 'Group By ' + @GroupBy + ' Order by ' + @GroupBy else '' end,'Select , ','Select ')
--Print @SQL
Exec (@SQL)


Set NoCount Off
Set Ansi_Warnings on
```